# steam won't open after install

Tags: 13.04, steam

I've looked all over the place for a solution but no one seems to be getting the same error codes as me. When I try to run Steam through terminal I get the following error:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1367621987_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1367621987_client)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1367621987_client)
[1013/104817:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(646)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/steamUI/../common/steam/client_api.cpp (281) : Assertion Failed: ClientAPI_InitGlobalInstance: InternalAPI_Init_Internal failed.

Assert( Assertion Failed: ClientAPI_InitGlobalInstance: InternalAPI_Init_Internal failed.
 ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/steamUI/../common/steam/client_api.cpp:281

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1367621987_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/assert_20131013104817_1.dmp
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/steamUI/SteamStartup.cpp (627) : Assertion Failed: ! "There was a problem with your Steam installation.\n" "Please reinstall steam.\n"
unlinked 2 orphaned pipes
CAsyncIOManager: 0 threads terminating.  0 reads, 0 writes, 0 deferrals.
CAsyncIOManager: 75 single object sleeps, 0 multi object sleeps
CAsyncIOManager: 0 single object alertable sleeps, 1 multi object alertable sleeps
[2013-10-13 10:48:16] Startup - updater built May  3 2013 15:08:27
[2013-10-13 10:48:16] Verifying installation...
[2013-10-13 10:48:16] Verification complete
Shutting down. . .
[2013-10-13 10:48:17] Shutdown
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-d172a742-b7dd-419c-b235-d60c32131013
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get purge` and terminal tries to tell me I don't have Steam installed. I've tried reinstalling with software center but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Steam community: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/828937546083456931/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Steam error, I found this topic at the Steam Commmunity: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/828937546083456931/

Anyway, if you want to uninstall Steam next to `sudo apt-get purge` you must indicate the package name you want to remove, and the steam package name is `steam-launcher`, so to uninstall (in this case a "purge" uninstall) steam you have to run this:

> sudo apt-get purge steam-launcher

If you want to remove also the steam user-data directory, you have to remove these two folders: `~/.local/share/Steam` and `~/.steam/` 
but **DO NOT remove the SteamApps directory inside `~/.local/share/Steam`** or all your downloaded games will be  removed!

Comment: Awesome! I followed both pieces of advice and I finally got steam working! Thank you muchly